# average of confusion matrix in R

Tags: r, data-mining, naivebayes

I applied 10 Cross-Validation and the output is 10 folds on confusion matrix so how can I find the average of the folds by confusion matrix?

and is my work is correct?

this my code :

```
set.seed(100)
    library(caTools)
    library(caret)
    library(e1071)
    folds<-createFolds(wpdc$outcome, k=10) 
    CV <- lapply(folds, function(x){
      traing_folds=wpdc[-x,]
      test_folds=wpdc[x,]
      dataset_model_nb<-naiveBayes(outcome ~ ., data = traing_folds)
      dataset_predict_nB<-predict(dataset_model_nb, test_folds[-1])
      dataset_table_nB<-table(test_folds[,1],dataset_predict_nB)
      accuracy<-confusionMatrix(dataset_table_nB, positive ="R")
      return(accuracy)
    })

 outcome radius_mean texture_mean perimeter_mean area_mean smoothness_mean compactness_mean concavity_mean concave_points_mean symmetry_mean fractal_dimension_mean radius_se texture_se perimeter_se area_se smoothness_se
1       N       18.02        27.60         117.50    1013.0         0.09489           0.1036         0.1086             0.07055        0.1865                0.06333    0.6249     1.8900        3.972   71.55      0.004433
2       N       17.99        10.38         122.80    1001.0         0.11840           0.2776         0.3001             0.14710        0.2419                0.07871    1.0950     0.9053        8.589  153.40      0.006399
3       N       21.37        17.44         137.50    1373.0         0.08836           0.1189         0.1255             0.08180        0.2333                0.06010    0.5854     0.6105        3.928   82.15      0.006167
```

Comment: Are you looking to calculate average cv accuracy? what does 'average of fold by confusion matrix' means ? Please provide a sample data set.

Comment: yes, the output is 10 confusion matrix, so I need the average (one confusion matrix ) I mean I need the average to be in confusion matrix way, I hope you understand me, thank you

Comment: 1. make your function return just the `matrix` i.e. `return(accuracy$table)`. 2. Use `Reduce` to sum the matrices in `CV` ie. `Reduce('+', CV)`

Comment: very helpful thank you

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same, then following the tip of @Stephen Handerson, what I was:

1. Define a list of matrices:

   - `rfConfusionMatrices <- list()`
2. Store each matrix inside that list:

   - `RrfConfusionMatrix[[i]] <- confMatrix`
3. Use the `Reduce` function to sum the matrices and divide by the folds:

   - `rfConfusionMatrixMean <- Reduce('+', rfConfusionMatrix) / nFolds`

Answer (score 0):

If you reorganize your code and store the predictions and the true labels as:

```
set.seed(100)
    library(caTools)
    library(caret)
    library(e1071)
    folds <- createFolds(wpdc$outcome, k=10) 
    CV <- lapply(folds, function(x){
      traing_folds=wpdc[-x,]
      test_folds=wpdc[x,]
      dataset_model_nb<-naiveBayes(outcome ~ ., data = traing_folds)
      dataset_predict_nB<-predict(dataset_model_nb, test_folds[-1])
      dataset_table_nB<-table(test_folds[,1],dataset_predict_nB)
      return(dataset_table_nB) # storing true and predicted values
    })
```

You can append them by reducing:

```
appended_table_nB<- do.call(rbind, dataset_table_nB)
```

And then take the confusion matrix:

```
accuracy <- confusionMatrix(appended_table_nB, positive ="R")
```

It is the same as taking the average. The only difference is that you sum the data points in the conf matrix, but the accuracy and other metrics are in their average. If you'd like to see the conf matrix as average, you can:

`averaged_matrix <- as.matrix(accuracy) / nFold`

Answer (score 0):

I just googled to find out whether it is a common thing to calculate a mean from confusion matrices. Just in case somebody is interested in a solution that can be adjusted to save more than just average values:

I defined the following function to get mean and standard deviation from a `list` of confusion matrices or similar objects, given that all of those matrices have the same format:

```
average_matr <- function(matr_list){
  if(class(matr_list[[1]])[1] == "confusionMatrix"){
    matr_lst <- lapply(matr_list, FUN = function(x){x$table})
  }else{
    matr_lst <- matr_list
  }
  vals <- lapply(matr_lst, as.numeric)
  matr <- do.call(cbind, vals)
  #vec_mean <- apply(matr, MARGIN = 1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  vec_mean <- rowMeans(matr, na.rm = TRUE)
  matr_mean <- matrix(vec_mean, nrow = nrow(matr_lst[[1]]))
  vec_sd <- apply(matr, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sd, na.rm = TRUE)
  matr_sd <- matrix(vec_sd, nrow = nrow(matr_lst[[1]]))
  out <- list(matr_mean, matr_sd)
  return(out)
}

average_matr(confusion_matr)
```

If the objects in the list are of the `confusionMatrix` class, the function will only extract the values. If it is a list of matrices, it will calculate mean and standard deviation.

Note that `rowMeans` is supposedly faster than `apply` with `FUN = mean`, however, as far as I know there is no `sd` function. While I used a similar syntax, `apply` with `mean` could be replaced, but for smaller data sets there should be no noticeable difference.

Edit: Added both versions.

**Additional: Include export as LaTeX table**

```
average_matr <- function(matr_list, latex_file = NA,
                         metric = "sd", return = TRUE){
  if(class(matr_list[[1]])[1] == "confusionMatrix"){
    matr_lst <- lapply(matr_list, FUN = function(x){x$table})
  }else{
    matr_lst <- matr_list
  }
  vals <- lapply(matr_lst, as.numeric)
  matr <- do.call(cbind, vals)
  #vec_mean <- apply(matr, MARGIN = 1, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  vec_mean <- rowMeans(matr, na.rm = TRUE)
  matr_mean <- matrix(vec_mean, nrow = nrow(matr_lst[[1]]))
  if(metric == "sd"){
    vec_sd <- apply(matr, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sd, na.rm = TRUE)
  }else if(metric == "se"){
    vec_sd <- apply(matr, MARGIN = 1,
                    FUN = function(x){sd(x, na.rm = TRUE)/sqrt(length(x))})
  }else{
    vec_sd <- NA
  }
  if(length(vec_sd) > 1){
    matr_sd <- matrix(vec_sd, nrow = nrow(matr_lst[[1]]))
    out <- list(matr_mean, matr_sd)
  }else{
    out <- matr_mean
  }
  # generate latex table
  if(is.character(latex_file)){
    if(dir.exists(dirname(latex_file))){
      sink(latex_file)
      cat("\\hline\n")
      cat(paste(row.names(matr_lst[[1]]), collapse = " & "), "\\\\\n")
      cat("\\hline\n")
      if(length(vec_sd) > 1){
        for(r in 1:nrow(matr_mean)){
          cat(paste(formatC(matr_mean[r, ], digits = 1, format = "f"),
                    formatC(matr_sd[r, ], digits = 1, format = "f"),
                    sep = " \\(\\pm\\) ", collapse = " & "), "\\\\\n")
        }
      }else{
        for(r in 1:nrow(matr_mean)){
          cat(paste(formatC(matr_mean, digits = 1, format = "f"),
                     collapse = " & "), "\\\\\n")
        }
      }
      cat("\\hline\n")
      sink()
    }else{
      warning("Directory not found: ", latex_file)
    }
  }
  if(return){
    return(out)
  }
}
```